# Modulus returning divide by zero exception

Tags: java

The code below throws a divide by zero exception at the 10th line.

```
int s2=10,mn=20;
n = 4*s2;  
i = n-1; 
j = 1;
while(i!=0){
    j*=2;
    i--;
}
Random rand=new Random();
r = Math.abs(rand.nextInt(4*mn)) % j;  // this line returns divide by zero exception
```

Comment: Good spotting. What's your question?

Comment: I want to know why,for ony that particular case.All the other cases just work fine

Comment: I think it occures, because you get an Integer Overflow, when you calculate 2^40.

Comment: So changing the data type to long would correct the problem,right??

Comment: Do you have a `while` for your `do`?

Comment: Thank you GAlexMES ,that was exactly the problem.Any number greater than 8 reports an error.

Comment: Yes,I do have a while for the do.The code is just a small snippet.Sorry for not attaching the while :)

Comment: Note: the `% j` doesn't do anything if `2^^(4*s2) > mn`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are playing with the big numbers you must be getting **Integer Overflow**

Answer (score 0):

You need to do code in try-catch block.So catch block will catch the exception, and you can handle as you wish.